# kura - cannot uninstall deployment package remotely(deploy-v2)

Tags: osgi, mqtt, kura

I am new to kura and I have been trying to remotely uninstall a deployment package using Amit's MQTT [application](https://github.com/amitjoy/Kura-MQTT-Client-Utility), but I am unable to do so. This is the request payload I send from the application-

dp.name=hello_osgi

job.id=12345891011L

dp.version=1.0.0

I get the following error in the response topic-

```
    -- listing properties --
    response.code=500
    response.exception.message=java.lang.String cannot be cast to java.lang.Long,
    response.exception.stack=java.lang.ClassCastException: java.lang.String cannot be cast to java.lang.Long           
            at org.eclipse.kura.core.deployment.uninstall.DeploymentPackageUninstallOptions.
            <init>(DeploymentPackageUninstallOptions.java:38)     
            at org.eclipse.kura.core.deployment.CloudDeploymentHandlerV2.doExecUninstall(CloudDeploymentHandlerV2.java:594)                
            at org.eclipse.kura.core.deployment.CloudDeploymentHandlerV2.doExec(CloudDeploymentHandlerV2.java:343)                
            at org.eclipse.kura.cloud.MessageHandlerCallable.call(Cloudlet.java:270)            
            at org.eclipse.kura.cloud.MessageHandlerCallable.call(Cloudlet.java:1)
            at java.util.concurrent.FutureTask.run(FutureTask.java:266)      
            at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.runWorker(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:1142)               
            at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:617)               
            at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:745) ,
            response.code=500

         Malformed uninstall request
```

Following is the kura console-

```
16:12:04,707 [MQTT Call: test-client] INFO  CloudServiceImpl:440  -               Message arrived on topic: $EDC/amir-kura/test-client/DEPLOY-V2/EXEC/uninstall
16:12:04,709 [pool-3-thread-2] ERROR CloudDeploymentHandlerV2:597  - Malformed uninstall request!
16:12:04,710 [pool-3-thread-2] INFO  DataServiceImpl:441  - Storing message on topic :$EDC/#account-name/CLIENT_QED0U1F74NLHA7M0Q5KI606QAU/DEPLOY-V2/REPLY/REQUEST_OTFGFHBKFSCVOI156408A4SU26, priority: 1
16:12:04,733 [DataServiceImpl:Submit] INFO  MqttDataTransport:512  - Publishing message on topic: $EDC/amir-kura/CLIENT_QED0U1F74NLHA7M0Q5KI606QAU/DEPLOY-V2/REPLY/REQUEST_OTFGFHBKFSCVOI156408A4SU26 with QoS: 0
16:12:04,745 [pool-3-thread-2] INFO  DataServiceImpl:444  - Stored message on topic :$EDC/#account-name/CLIENT_QED0U1F74NLHA7M0Q5KI606QAU/DEPLOY-V2/REPLY/REQUEST_OTFGFHBKFSCVOI156408A4SU26, priority: 1
```

Is there some other way to send the request payload ?

Answer (score 0):

A quick look at [DeploymentPackageUninstallOptions](https://github.com/eclipse/kura/blob/98349bfdf5eba99a3c8f1a5816e86719aca5711f/kura/org.eclipse.kura.core.deployment/src/main/java/org/eclipse/kura/core/deployment/uninstall/DeploymentPackageUninstallOptions.java#L38) reveals that you are sending `job.id` as a **String** instead of a **Long**.

Instead of

```
String reqId = "12345891011L";
payload.addMetric("job.id", reqId);
```

the code should do

```
long reqId = 12345891011L;
payload.addMetric("job.id", reqId);
```

Or better, use [KuraUninstallPayload](https://github.com/eclipse/kura/blob/98349bfdf5eba99a3c8f1a5816e86719aca5711f/kura/org.eclipse.kura.core.deployment/src/main/java/org/eclipse/kura/core/deployment/uninstall/KuraUninstallPayload.java) which already implements all methods with the correct type.

I don't know Amit's MQTT UTility, but I think you can set the type of the variable in some way (or change his application to set the correct type and then send a pull request).

Comment: I had figured this out that `job.id` needs to be long and kura is getting it as String, hence the error. My goal is to make a web application capable of remotely installing, uninstalling, starting, stopping a bundle via MQTT messages as shown [here](http://eclipse.github.io/kura/ref/mqtt-namespace.html). I don't know if I can use the Kura API in the web application I don't think I can, so how should I send these metrics ?

Comment: Check how MQTT Utility sends the packets and do the same. Last time I checked (~1 year ago) KuraPayload was basically a Map which was serialized using Protobuf library.